# Where does IIS Express write log files for VS2017 / .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, iis-express

I have a .NET Core 2.2 Web API project hosted by IIS Express and trying to find the w3c log files for some failed requests.

My solution level .vs\config\applicationhost.config has the following:

`<siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
 </siteDefaults>`

If I try to browse to %IIS_USER_HOME%, I get error dialog saying Windows can't find "%IIS_USER_HOME%".   How do I find this folder?

VS2017
Windows 10
.NET Core 2.2

Comment: `%IIS_USER_HOME%` translates to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\`

Answer (score 2):

Copied from the comment.

The first few lines of the `applicationHost.config` file actually indicate the values,

```
<!--
    IIS configuration sections.
    For schema documentation, see
    %IIS_BIN%\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml.

    Please make a backup of this file before making any changes to it.
    NOTE: The following environment variables are available to be used
          within this file and are understood by the IIS Express.
          %IIS_USER_HOME% - The IIS Express home directory for the user
          %IIS_SITES_HOME% - The default home directory for sites
          %IIS_BIN% - The location of the IIS Express binaries
          %SYSTEMDRIVE% - The drive letter of %IIS_BIN%
-->
```

So the actual value for `%IIS_USER_HOME%` is `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress`.

Comment: Jexus Manager also resolves the environment variables in this manner, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v12.0.68.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Helper.cs#L34